# Unable to find 'jsinterop/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml' on your classpath

Tags: gwt, vaadin

During setting up new environment (new machine), I got the following error:

```
--- vaadin-maven-plugin:8.17.0:compile (compile_theme) @ xxx
[INFO] auto discovered modules [AppWidgetset]
[INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler version 8.17.0
[INFO] Loading inherited module 'AppWidgetset'
[INFO]    Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'
[INFO]       Loading inherited module 'jsinterop.annotations.Annotations'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Unable to find 'jsinterop/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

It runs fine on old machine.

I am in the process of migrating Vaadin 8 to Vaadin 14. The eclipse version 2020-06(4.16.0), embedded maven version is 3.6.3 and Java 8 is used.

During investigation I found there is a difference on dependency tree:

```
--old machine
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-push:jar:8.17.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:jar:8.17.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-client:jar:8.17.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (com.vaadin:vaadin-shared:jar:8.17.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar:8.17.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- com.google.gwt:gwt-elemental:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:jar:sources:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |        +- (javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile - version managed from 2.0.0.Final; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |        +- (javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided - version managed from 3.1.0; scope managed from compile; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        \- (org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-core:jar:14.8.10:compile
```

**com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations is not added on new environment**

```
--new machine
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-push:jar:8.17.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:jar:8.17.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-client:jar:8.17.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (com.vaadin:vaadin-shared:jar:8.17.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar:8.17.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- com.google.gwt:gwt-elemental:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-core:jar:14.8.10:compile
```

Can anybody help to figure out what's happening? Thank you in advance

Comment: Are there other warnings when you build? For example, if you are installing gwt dependencies manually (instead of fetching them from maven central or your own proxy server), you could have skipped gwt-user's pom, so its dependencies are missing?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't see any other warnings, but I notice there is difference. In old machine, compiler says "AppWidgetset is up to date. GWT compilation skipped", while compiler says "Loading inherited module 'AppWidgetset'" in new machine.

Comment: Since you're using 8.17, that means you're using an Extended Maintenance version and thus eligible for support; I recommend getting in contact with Vaadin about the issue.

Comment: Being "up to date" just means that it has built since there were changes, so the plugin decided not to run. Consider running `mvn clean` on the old machine to force a new build for more apples-to-apples comparison. Note that this might not work if you build outside of `target/`.